# Is there any way to create a fake from a System.Type object in FakeItEasy?

Tags: autofac, fakeiteasy

Is there any way to create a fake from a System.Type object in FakeItEasy? Similar to:

```
var instance = A.Fake(type);
```

I try to write a fake container for AutoFac that automatically return fakes for all resolved types. I have looked in the code for FakeItEasy and all methods that support this is behind internal classes but I have found the interface IFakeObjectContainer that looks pretty interesting, but the implementations still need registration of objects that is the thing that I want to come around.

Comment: A glance over the FakeItEasy API would suggest they don't support this. However, I could be wrong.  An alternative would be to use the AutoMockContainer in [AutofacContrib](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/downloads/list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of FakeItEasy 2.1.0 (but do consider upgrading to the latest release for more features and better bugfixes), you can [create a fake from a Type](http://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/creating-fakes/#natural-fakes) like so:

```
using FakeItEasy.Sdk;

…

object fake = Create.Fake(type);
```

If you *must* use an earlier release, you could use some reflection based approach to create a method info for the A.Fake() method. (since it's about auto mocking this shouldn't be a problem really).

Comment: Actually, you could support interfaces only out of the box: A.Fake<object>(x => x.Implements(typeof(yourTypeHere)));

Comment: I just downloaded the latest version of FakeItEasy and can still not find a way to do this. Is there a method that I am missing or didn't this feature manage to get into this release?

Answer (score 1):

This is best done using a registration handler. You should look into how AutofacContrib.Moq implements its [`MoqRegistrationHandler`](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/contrib/Source/AutofacContrib.Moq/MoqRegistrationHandler.cs). You'll see that it is actually using the generic method `MockRepository.Create` to make fake instances. Creating a similar handler for FakeItEasy should be quite simple.